# Posicionamento Javascript

Tags: javascript

Pessoal estou usando o seguinte carousel para passar uns cards https://codepen.io/douglas-l-dutra/pen/zbyQwL 
porém ele mostra apenas 3 cards, como faria pra exibir 6 cards ocupando assim o grid de 12 partes do bootstrap

Comment: Pesquisei sobre o assunto, o único código que achei, que faz exatamente o que você precisa é esse [aqui](https://www.bootply.com/M4ar8XLItz#) espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Perfeito meu amigo! Thanks